# How to understand the real effect of an independent variable on the response?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multivariate-analysis

I am aware the question is a bit generic, but any hint that would point me in the right direction is welcomed.

Consider I have a dataset with few variables:

- gender
- type of education (bachelor/master)
- geographical region (europe/asia/...)
- level of english (A1 to C2)
- salary (in PPP USD)

Now I test for difference of mean in salaries between the two education groups and find out that the two types of program have statistically significant differences. Then I test for differences between gender, and also the gender does.

Now say I also see that most of the women are in the bachelor, so that the differences between and women and men could be justified by the type of program.

How can I mathematically/statistically account for these "effects" and understand the true impact of education or gender?

This might apply to any combination of variables. The real question is: how can I understand which are the most important variables that have an effect on the salary, and understand their real effect whitout jumping to wrong conclusions?

Comment: By "real effect" do you mean "causal effect"? If yes, then you can start by reading some CV threads on causal analysis. See the [tag:causality] tag.

Comment: @dipetkov I know that "causal" is a major words. Say the closest I can get to that without waking up some monsters.